# Can't figure out this simple perl error?

Tags: perl

For an array i am checkinit setting some condition in foreach loop. only if it is true, i want to assign `$_` to another array.. but the simple `@stale = $_;` is not appending to it.. neither is `push` or any other function for that matter..

Any idea what can be done to resolve this?

**Edit: Code from comment by OP**

```
# To give a generic ORACLE_HOME and HOSTNAME path for all the instances.
#
#using shell ENV variable in perl
my $home  = $ENV{'ORACLE_HOME'};
#
#concatenating the paths
my $subdir = "/ccr/hosts/";
my $subdir1 = $home.$subdir;
my $host = "`hostname`/state/review";
my $subdir2 = $subdir1.$host;
#
#assigning each row of command output to an array
@infile = `ls -ltr $subdir2`;
#
#printing each value of the array i.e. file details
foreach (@infile) {
        chop($_);
        $m_age = -M $_;
        if (($stale = `date` - $m_age) < 1.0) {
#
#
#change/correct this line :(
#
#
                printf "\nFile %s was last modified 24hrs back. stale collections. \n" , $_ , $m_age ,$stale;
                push @stale_files , $_;
        }
        else {
        @not_stale_files = $_[$q++];
        }
        $count++;
}
print "\n for stale:\n";
foreach $i (@stale_files) {
print "$stale_files[$i]\n";
}
```

Also, each time the loop executes, `$_` value is expected to be appended to `@stale`. But only the last value of `$_` (obtained during the last time loop runs) is getting assigned to `@stale`.

Comment: Could you please post a code snippet of what you are doing? `@array = $value` is not valid but `push @array, $value` should work.

Comment: Can you post some more code? (as I left my crystal ball at home today)

Comment: sure check back in 5 mins [ but only this time, next time make sure to carry your crystal ball;) JK!]

Comment: @Matteo : see comment to Dave's answer!

Comment: `qx(date) - $m_age` is almost surely not doing what you think. If you are just trying to test whether a file has not been modified in the last day, just say `-M $filename > 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok let's review the edited code

Please use

```
use warnings;
use strict;
```

in your code: it will help you detect errors

```
# To give a generic ORACLE_HOME and HOSTNAME path for all the instances.
#
#using shell ENV variable in perl
my $home  = $ENV{'ORACLE_HOME'};
#
#concatenating the paths
my $subdir = "/ccr/hosts/";
my $subdir1 = $home.$subdir;
```

you don't need to have complicated constructs

```
my $subdir1 = $ENV{'ORACLE_HOME} . '/ccr/hosts';
```

is enough

The next line will not work: back ticks will not be expanded in a `"` quoted string

```
my $host = "`hostname`/state/review";
my $host = `hostname` . '/state/review';

my $subdir2 = $subdir1.$host;
#
#assigning each row of command output to an array
@infile = `ls -ltr $subdir2`;
```

Here `@infile` will contain more than the files. Each element will have the output of `ls -ltr`. Something like

```
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 corti  corti   94 Sep 14 11:40 test.pl~
-rw-r--r--  1 corti  corti  979 Sep 14 11:49 test.pl

#
#printing each value of the array i.e. file details
foreach (@infile) {
    chop($_);
```

here you are doing something like `-M -rw-r--r--  1 corti  corti   94 Sep 14 11:40 test.pl~`.

```
    $m_age = -M $_;
    if (($stale = `date` - $m_age) < 1.0) {
       #
       #
       #change/correct this line :(
       #
       #
       printf "\nFile %s was last modified 24hrs back. stale collections. \n" , $_ , $m_age ,$stale;
```

It is correct. The problem is in the content of `$_`

```
            push @stale_files , $_;
    }
    else {
```

`$_` is an element of `@infile`. What do you want to achieve whith `$_[]`? What is `$q`?

```
    @not_stale_files = $_[$q++];
    }
```

Also `$count` is never initialized

```
    $count++;
}
print "\n for stale:\n";
foreach $i (@stale_files) {
  print "$stale_files[$i]\n"; 
}
```

Comment: `($stale = date - $m_age)` overwrites the scalar `$stale`. It doesn't touch the array `@stale` in any way.

Comment: Agree (will edit) but this means he has a $stale and @stale variable and maybe is mixing them up.

Answer (score 0):

Using "`push @stale, $_;`" (which adds to the end of the array) instead of "`@stale = $_;`" (which completely replaces the existing contents of the array) should work in this case.

**Edit:** Proof that `push` does what is asked.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @numbers = (1, 8, 3, 5, 2, 8, 9, 0);
my @stale;

for (@numbers) {
    if ($_ < 5) {
        printf "\nNumber %s is less than five.\n", $_;
        push @stale, $_;
    }   
}

print join ", ", @stale;
print "\n";
```

Output:

```
$ ./add_to_array.pl 

Number 1 is less than five.

Number 3 is less than five.

Number 2 is less than five.

Number 0 is less than five.
1, 3, 2, 0
$
```

Comment: I tried this already.. just the last value which $_ assumes is getting appended when i print @stale, where as its supposed to append $_ for each loop run [there is a loop inside which the code runs]

Comment: It definately loops more than once...  It may be worth displaying the code for the loop as well.

Comment: Yes it would be useful to have the whole script (reduced to reproduce the problem)

Comment: @Gshaw: See the code added to my answer. `push` does exactly what you're asking for. If @stale is ending up with only a single value, then your problem is somewhere outside of the code you provided.

Comment: @Dave: yes he is also assigning to `$stale` in the if clause

Comment: @Matteo: Not relevant. `$stale` and `@stale` are two independent, unrelated variables which happen to share a confusing similarity of name, the same as, say, `$comment` and `$comments`.